# Stack overflow when replacing ' with '' in VB 6.0

Tags: string, ms-access, vb6, replace, stack-overflow

I'm looking into some legacy VB 6.0 code (an Access XP application) to solve a problem with a SQL statement by the Access app. I need to use replace single quotes with 2 single quotes for cases where a customer name has an apostrophe in the name (e.g. "Doctor's Surgery":

```
Replace(customerName, "'", "''")
```

Which will escape the single quote, so I get the valid SQL:

```
SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE customer = 'Doctor''s Surgery'
```

Unfortunately the Replace function causes an infinite loop and stack overflow, presumably because it replace function recursively converts each added quote with another 2 quotes. E.g. one quote is replaced by two, then that second quote is also replaced by two, and so on...

----------------EDIT---------------

I have noticed (thanks to posters) that the replace function used in this project is custom-written:

```
Public Function replace(ByVal StringToSearch As String, ByVal ToLookFor As String,
ByVal ToReplaceWith As String) As String
Dim found As Boolean
Dim position As Integer
Dim result As String

position = 0
position = InStr(StringToSearch, ToLookFor)
If position = 0 Then
    found = False
    replace = StringToSearch
    Exit Function
Else
    result = Left(StringToSearch, position - 1)
    result = result & ToReplaceWith
    result = result & Right(StringToSearch, Len(StringToSearch) - position - Len(ToLookFor) + 1)
    result = replace(result, ToLookFor, ToReplaceWith)
End If
replace = result

End Function
```

Apparently, VB didn't always have a replace function of it's own. This implementation must be flawed. An going to follow folk's advice and remove it in favour of VB 6's implementation - if this doesn't work, I will write my own which works. Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: Constructing strings like this is prone to SQL INjection Attacks...

Comment: Agreed, it is vulnerable to SQL injection. The whole code base is awful - I have just taken it on a support contract, because the developer or company who wrote it isn't around anymore... we don't want to re-write the thing, just maintain it!

Comment: Back in good old VB6 days we used to do this all the time with no stack overflow. Are you sure this is the cause of your stack overflow?

Comment: @rein: THat's what I'm thinking too...

Comment: Almost certain - the call stack is an endless list of [[MyProject]].Defaults.replace - is the replace function supposed to be in the Defaults module?

Comment: eeeeek: not only is that an horrendous recursive replace function, it will be orders of magnitude slower than the built-in one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not a proprietary implementation of the Replace function?

If so it can just be replaced by VB6's Replace.

I can't remember which version it appeared in (it wasn't in Vb3, but was in VB6) so if the original code base was vb3/4 it could be a hand coded version.

**EDIT**

I just saw your edit, I was Right!

Yes, you should be able to just remove that function, it'll then use the in build VB6 replace function.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is a custom-written Replace function, which i didn't realise (see my edited post). I will try to remove it and see what happens...

Comment: You have to watch for that in really old Access apps. Access 97 was built on VB5 which did not have a Replace function, so you may run across that from time to time.

Comment: Oorang: I thought it was a late addition, but wasn't sure if it appeared in 5 or 6. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2):

We use an VB6 application that has the option of replacing ' with ` or removing them completely.

You could also walk through the letters, building a second string and inserting each ' as ''.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this in Access and it works fine (no stackoverflow):

```
 Public Function ReplaceSingleQuote(tst As String) As String
        ReplaceSingleQuote = Replace(tst, "'", "''")
 End Function


 Public Sub TestReplaceSingleQuote()
        Debug.Print ReplaceSingleQuote("Doctor's Surgery")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, the Replace function isn't the problem - unless it's a proprietary implementation of replace, from legacy Vb code, before replace was included

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is a custom-written Replace function, which i didn't realise (see my edited post). I guess the solution is to write my own?

Comment: @James Allen: just use the one built into VB